# How to load jQuery in the footer - nothing works for me

Tags: functions, themes, jquery, footer

I tried all the solutions I found on the internet, including the ones I found here, but nothing works on my theme - jQuery always load in header. I try to use the one from Google, but I would be happy to use the local one too, only in footer.
 This is what I have now:

```
   function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.10.2', false, '1.10.2', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        // load a JS file from my theme: js/theme.js
        //wp_enqueue_script('my_script', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/theme.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

Any ideas why no solution works for me?

Comment: So you have a `wp_footer()` defined in the footer, right?

Comment: yes, I do have.

Comment: Maybe you have another script loading it via a plugin, or maybe it's hard-coded in the theme.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load your scripts in the footer so you'll need to add them to the functions.

This method works for parent themes dependent on jQuery.

**For child themes**

Change:

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

To

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
```

**Example code for parent themes:**

```
function wpsites_load_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpsites_load_scripts' );
```

**The 5th parameter** determines where the script is loaded:

**$in_footer**

Normally, scripts are placed in  of the HTML document. If this parameter is true, the script is placed before the  end tag. This **requires the theme to have the wp_footer() template tag** in the appropriate place.

**Default: false**

Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: sorry, I do not understand how that is related to loading jQuery in the footer. I'm only interested in jQuery.

Comment: The relation is that jQuery cannot load in the footer unless every other script that relies on it also loads in the footer.

Comment: You need to tell WordPress where to load each script using the 5th parameter. The default for $in_footer is false so you need to change that to true for each script in using the wp_enqueue_scripts function so it hooks into wp_footer().

Comment: I use minify, with WTC, and I'm loading all the javascrip in footer. The only script that is loading in header is css. is css required to load in the footer too?

Comment: I would check that all scripts using jQuery are loaded in the footer and then flush all caching. CSS doesn't use jQuery.

Comment: I'm looking in the source code, and yes, no javascript (except for external javascript) is loading before footer. Flushing cache was also used.

Comment: You need to check the code. Link to your site please

Comment: http://www.soundtrackmania.com/ - I even disabled the plugins that you can see now, which are using some jquery in the header, but it was the same.